# How to make traefik work with graylog2?

Tags: graylog2, traefik

I'm getting this error when entering to web interface url:

```
 Server currently unavailable
We are experiencing problems connecting to the Graylog server running on http://127.0.0.1:9000/api. Please verify that the server is healthy and working correctly.

You will be automatically redirected to the previous page once we can connect to the server.

Do you need a hand? We can help you.

More details
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
graylog:
    image: graylog2/server:2.3.0-1
    environment:
      GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET: xxx
      GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2: xxx
      GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI: http://example.com/api/
      GRAYLOG_REST_LISTEN_URI:  http://0.0.0.0:9000/api/
      GRAYLOG_WEB_LISTEN_URI: http://0.0.0.0:9000/
      GRAYLOG_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NAME: graylog
      GRAYLOG_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://graylog-elasticsearch:9200
    depends_on:
      - graylog-elasticsearch
      - mongo
    networks:
      - traefik
      - default
      - graylog
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.port=9000"
        - "traefik.tags=logging"
        - "traefik.docker.network=infra_traefik"
        - "traefik.backend=graylog"
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.name == manager-1
```

As you see everything should work without any problem.

Here's what netstat shows:

```
root@6399d2a13c5d:/usr/share/graylog# netstat -tulnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:42255        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:51199        0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

Here's container printenv:

```
    root@6399d2a13c5d:/usr/share/graylog# printenv
    GRAYLOG_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NAME=graylog
    HOSTNAME=6399d2a13c5d
    TERM=xterm
    GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI=http://example.com/api/
    GRAYLOG_REST_LISTEN_URI=http://0.0.0.0:9000/api/
    GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=ччч
    CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION=20140324
    GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=ччч
    GRAYLOG_REST_TRANSPORT_URI=http://example.com/api/
    PWD=/usr/share/graylog
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
    LANG=C.UTF-8
    JAVA_VERSION=8u72
    SHLVL=1
    HOME=/root
    JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION=8u72-b15-1~bpo8+1
    GRAYLOG_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://graylog-elasticsearch:9200
    GRAYLOG_WEB_LISTEN_URI=http://0.0.0.0:9000/
    GOSU_VERSION=1.7
    GRAYLOG_SERVER_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx2g -XX:NewRatio=1 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -server -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
    _=/usr/bin/printenv
```

I assume problem maybe within this custom header which graylog probably need:

```
RequestHeader set X-Graylog-Server-URL "http://graylog.example.org/api/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the implementation example you have given I am assuming that `example.org` is a remote host rather than `127.0.0.1`. In that situation, you are correct in assuming that the additional header is needed.
From my experience you should strip `api/` for the the end user web access

You will need to set the request header `X-Graylog-Server-URL`. eg `curl -H "X-Graylog-Server-URL: http://graylog.example.org/"  http://127.0.0.1:9000`.
[Graylog web proxy config](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/configuration/web_interface.html) gives some good info if you want to setup a webserver in front of your graylog server. It's just a pity that (at the time of writing this) the [Docker Examples](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/installation/docker.html) do not include a basic nginx config

I am using kubernetes and had to add the following to my ingress annotation to get traffic in correctly

```
ingress:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header X-Graylog-Server-URL https://$server_name/;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should just use

```
GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI=http://<your-host-ip>/api/
```

without rest URI settings.

Comment: this <your-host-ip> recommendation is less than worthless, you obscurify it even more. You could mean anything by that. The point is, that graylog must be able to bind to this exact address. The other way round it seems that another hosts must be able to connect. So something like <your-host-ip> is not possible in sNAT or scheduled cluster environments, because the host ip does vary.